# Laravel Vapor serve assets from domain root with get parameters

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, shopify-app, laravel-vapor

I am using Laravel Vapor to build a Shopify app. As the Shopify App requires some javascript files included to the user's store I am Shopify's scripttag functionality to provide URLs of assets to get included.
I am experiencing the following issue.
Laravel Vapor by default makes the static resources available through the public S3 "asset" bucket or the AWS CloudFront CDN network. I need those assets to be available from the domain root. Vapor has the possibility to onclude assets which are accessible from the root domain, but in my case this doesn`t to the job.
With the following configuration I am trying to allow the mentioned asset to be loaded from the domain root.

```
    'serve_assets' => [
        'scripttags/onload.js'
    ],
```

The problem the way Shopify injects those assets is with get parameter like **{assetUrl}?shop=usersstore.myshopify.com**.
I need a way to allow wildcard asset addresses to be served by the root domain.
Something I tried and it doesn' work is:

```
    'serve_assets' => [
        'scripttags/onload.js*'
    ],
```

If you need more information or have questions ask in the comments.
Thank you for the time and hope to find an answer soon.

Comment: Hey I know this is from a while ago but did you ever solve this?